# WP All Import Plugin - Image Foreach loop

Tags: xml, wordpress, plugins, foreach, wpallimport

I'm a WordPress beginner so please bear with me. I'm currently using *WP All Import* to import my data, and there are a few images are stored as child elements of some parent element.

Following are the screen shot of the XML which exported from phpMyAdmin. The structure is different from what I see from *WP All Import* [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAPGfWd13-w). I'm not sure whether this is correct but the data can imported successfully.

[image]
[image]

From the screen shot (please take note on red boxes), I have same information with different id and images. My question is can I use the Foreach loop for my case? And how to write the Foreach loop based on my case?

This is the code I took from *WP All Import* website. But I cannot follow exactly same as my XML has different structure.

```
Example XML:

<images>
<image src=”image1.jpg” alt=”i am first image”>Featured Image</image>
<image src=”image2.jpg” alt=”this is image2″>Second Image</image>
<image src=”image3.jpg” alt=”this is image3″>Third Image</image>
<image src=”image4.jpg” alt=”this is image4″>Fourth Image</image>
</images>

Use the following FOREACH loop:

[FOREACH({images/image})]
http://www.example.com/my-folder/{@src},
[ENDFOREACH]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using SQL `GROUP CONCAT` to combine all the images into same id.

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT concat('<img><url>',filename,'</url></img>') SEPARATOR '\n')
FROM album_pictures 
GROUP BY album_id
```

So this is the result:

[image]

The I used FOREACH loop to read all the images.

```
[FOREACH({column[22]/img})]
http://www.example.com/my-folder/{url[1]}
[ENDFOREACH]
```